# TotalMinutes in TimeSpan with only 2 decimals

Tags: c#, timespan

I need to get the TotalMinutes in TimeSpan with just with only 2 decimal places, the 2 decimals refer to Seconds which the decimal should not be exceeded by 59. If exceeds, the whole number will be added. like for example:

```
1.59
```

1 minute and 59 seconds, if this adds one second it is counted as a Minute

```
2.00
```

I tried this code below:

```
var a_sec: float = 0.0;
var a_dec: float = 0.0;

a_sec= TimeSpan.Parse(add).TotalMinutes;
a_dec=Math.Round(a_sec,2);
```

but this won't work on mine, the error shows: 
Object doesn't support this property or method.

Comment: i tried the Math.Round, but this won't work on mine, i don't why

Comment: a_sec= TimeSpan.Parse(add).TotalMinutes;
a_dec=Math.Round(a_sec,2);

Comment: Add the code you have tried to the question

Comment: Are you *asking* for how to format a string using a decimal point to separate minutes and seconds?  Or are you *asserting* that that's what numbers after a decimal mean?  (because they don't)

Answer (score 3):

I guess something like

```
string.Format("{0:0}.{1:00}", Math.Truncate(ts.TotalMinutes), ts.Seconds);
```

would work.

Answer (score 1):

Here is example how to convert Minutes in double(with decimal part 0-99) to Real Minutes(decimal part 0-59):

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Your code goes here
        TimeSpan a = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2);
        TimeSpan b = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1.95);
        TimeSpan c = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1.97);
        TimeSpan d = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1.99);

        Console.WriteLine(GetRealMinutesDouble(a));   // out - 2
        Console.WriteLine(GetRealMinutesDouble(b));   // out - 1,57
        Console.WriteLine(GetRealMinutesDouble(c));   // out - 1,58
        Console.WriteLine(GetRealMinutesDouble(d));   // out - 1,59
    }
    public static double GetRealMinutesDouble(TimeSpan a )
    {
        var aSecondsPart = a.TotalMinutes - Math.Truncate(a.TotalMinutes);// Cut the decimal part which shows the seconds
        var aSecondsPartInRealSeconds = Math.Round(aSecondsPart*60/100*100)/100;// convert them to the interval 0-59
        return Math.Truncate(a.TotalMinutes)+aSecondsPartInRealSeconds;//add them back
    }
}
```